# when do I need to add an asset to config.assets.precompile and when not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm a little confused by when I need to add an asset to `config.assets.precompile` and when it's not necessary.

(It's possible that my problem may stem from the fact that this app was migrated from rails 2.x; at some point soon I'm going to rebuild it from the ground up as a 3.x app, but don't have the time for that yet.)

Here's my issue: I have a `.css` and `.js` files that are not being found by sprockets unless I add them to `config.assets.precompile` in `application.rb`.  I can't imagine I have to do this for every `.js` and `.css`, do I?

For example, one file I'm having this issue with is `app/assets/stylesheets/facybox.css`.

`application.css` is:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_directory .
*/
```

(yes, `require_directory` instead of `require_tree` intentionally).

I run `rake assets:precompile` on my server during deploy.  The resulting `application.css` has the contents of `facybox.css` in it.

`facybox.css` is referred to in a partial, like this:

```
<% content_for :header do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "facybox" %>
<% end %>
```

But when I go to a page that includes the partial, I get:

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError in Admin#compositions
Showing /srv/zmx/releases/5420c4dde6fbec53d78cffe78396085f263ed039/app/views/shared/_preview_assets.erb where line #6 raised:
facybox.css isn't precompiled
```

which I assume is because sprockets is looking for the fingerprinted copy of the file, which doesn't exist **unless** I add it to `config.assets.precompile`.  Then all is hunky-dory.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for precompiling are simple:

If an asset is required in one of the application manifests you do not need to add it to precompile.

If an asset needs to be referenced directly in a Rails view then you DO need to add it (and you should remove it from any manifests).

Answer (score 1):

As you said yourself, the contents of `facybox.css` are already included in your `application.css`.

This means that you can just remove the `stylesheet_link_tag` from your partial and also any other places where you use `facybox.css`. You would have to do the same for all other stylesheets that you already have included in your `application.css`